# How do I change a users default shell in OSX?

Tags: shell, macos

What is the correct OSX way of changing a users default shell? When I googled for it I found several references to an application called NetInfo Manager but I couldn't find it on my system. There were also references to a command line version called niutil which I didn't find either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set my shell in Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/48226/how-do-i-set-my-shell-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

for <=10.4 - netinfo manager, /users/whoever/shell

for >=10.5

1. Go to System Preferences -> Users & Groups
2. Click the lock icon to unlock the preference pane
3. Right-click (or control-click) on user and select "advanced options"
4. Edit login shell field

Comment: Wow, after 8 years of using OS X I didn't know about control clicking in the users prefs: I guess this was added in 10.5 though as you pointed out. +1

Comment: Control-Click is stunnning!

Comment: Lifesaver after moving my account's shell out of the PATH... couldn't start Terminal to fix via command line!

Comment: It doesn't work anymore on el Capitan?

Comment: True, this is the issue with this kind of thing, 7 years down the line and things have changed - why not do some research yourself, add and answer and it'll get upvoted, that's how things work, better than just sniping little answers

Comment: Please make sure your shell is added to `/etc/shells` first.

Answer (score 36):

```
sudo chsh -s /path/to/shell username
```

where shell is the one you want for that user. `sudo` is not needed if you know `username`'s password.

```
man chsh
```

for more examples.

Comment: works too for root for su, which isn't visible in control panel. I think?

Comment: You can also run just `chsh` and change the shell field. If you get an error like `chsh: /usr/local/bin/bash: non-standard shell`, add `/usr/local/bin/bash` to `/etc/shells`.

Comment: Maybe something changed in 10.9, but this command now throws a usage message. It seems the correct syntax is now `chsh -s /path/to/shell username`

Answer (score 10):

NetInfo has been replaced by Directory Services (dscl) and it can be noted the default shell for Mac OS X since 10.3 has been bash. Prior to that it was tcsh.

If you need to do this from the command line (eg. for pushing via ARD or remotely via SSH) you can run:

```
sudo dscl localhost -change /Local/Default/Users/USERNAME shell OLD_SHELL NEW_SHELL
#In Use:
sudo dscl localhost -change /Local/Default/Users/chealion shell /bin/bash /bin/zsh
```

If you're not sure of the current shell you can run:

```
sudo dscl localhost -read /Local/Default/Users/USERNAME shell
```

If the user is not a local user the path will simply change and if necessary you would change `localhost` to the name of your Open Directory Server. (Assuming it runs 10.5).

The info is stored in .plists (xml) in `/private/var/db/dslocal/` - you don't want to edit the plist files by hand however.

Answer (score 8):

For 10.10:

not `shell` but `UserShell`:

```
sudo dscl localhost -change /Local/Default/Users/USERNAME UserShell /bin/bash /bin/ksh
```