# How do I remove SSHFS's Terminal library?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal.app

I installed OS X FUSE and SSHFS from the [official site](http://osxfuse.github.io/). Now whenever I type in `ssh xxx@xxx.xx`, the terminal window is different. Some folders are blue and the window is different; it's not the way it was before I installed FUSE and SSHFS. Now the title of the terminal window is `xxx@xxx:~`, each line is `[xxx@xxx ~]$`, and startup notices are missing.

I'd like to uninstall that, but I don't know how. I followed the github directions to uninstall FUSE/SSHFS but I guess it didn't remove the Terminal modifications it made.

I'd assume this has something to do with a Terminal add-on package (`sshfs-2.5.0.pkg`) I installed for SSHFS because I only started to have this after I installed it (I had FUSE before). However, I uninstalled the package (it seems, `sshfs` commands aren't working) but the Terminal is still weird when I use `ssh`. Anyone know what it did and how to fix it? If not to fix it, how would I reset Terminal completely (remove all add-on's/packages, don't really care at this point)?

Answer (score 0):

The packages aren't "Terminal add-ons". They're just add-ons you install *via* the Terminal, much like videos on YouTube aren't really "Firefox videos" nor "Safari videos".

Likewise, the Terminal itself is only a renderer for programs running inside – first a *shell*, which interprets your commands, then various individual tools that you use. The appearance of the *prompt* (the `[login@hostname ~]$` prefix) is determined by your shell, and the coloured file list is enabled by a `ls` option.

Finally, each system has its own configuration. Running `ssh` basically connects you to another system's terminal, like Remote Desktop would – there is almost nothing on your computer that could change the behavior of remote servers that you're merely ssh'ing to. That is, if you ssh somewhere and see an unusual prompt, then it has been changed on *that* system.

---

…Unless you meant connecting *from* other systems *to* your computer. In which case, it's possible that the sshfs package might have changed the shell used by Terminal. Try `echo $SHELL` to check which one you're currently using (though sometimes `ps $$` can be more reliable), and [chsh](https://superuser.com/q/379725/1686) to change it back to the usual `/bin/bash`.

Additionally, check the files `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` for any additions at the bottom; look specifically for `PS1=` (which is the setting for the prompt's appearance).