# Killed shell by trying to change shell type which failed to install

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I managed to kill all access to the shell by trying to install [fish shell](http://fishshell.com) via brew and then set the default shell to fish via:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish
```

Unfortunately `fish` doesn’t seem to exist (I didn’t read the install errors from brew properly) and now the Terminal just quits when loading.

How can I reset the shell to bash without using the shell?

Comment: Do you have another user? That command would only have affected your user so you could log in as `foo`, switch to root and then fix things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the shell back to Bash—or any other installed shell—via the Mac OS X “Users & Groups”/“Accounts” preference pane under system preferences.

Here are instructions adapted [from this 2009 answer](https://superuser.com/a/48241/167207) on how to change a user’s default shell in Mac OS X:

1. Open “System Preferences.”
2. Open the “Accounts”/“Users & Groups” preference pane and unlock the preference pane if applicable.
3. On the user you wish to change the shell, <kbd>control</kbd>+click or right click on the user and choose “Advanced Options…”
4. Where it says “Login Shell:” change this to the shell you wish to use; in this case, change it to `/bin/bash`.

Note that “Login Shell:” is not a blank text field; it has a pull-down menu with a full list of installed shells you can use.